# Android in-app purchase inventory returns zero products

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm following the Android in-app purchasing example (in-app-billing-v03) and get success returned from the the setup and inventory query, which I guess means that the app itself is being recognised correctly.  However, I am not getting any products returned in the inventory even though I have two configured in the developer console for the app.

The app is in 'draft' status (apk uploaded, store listing and pricing completed in developer console), the in-app products show as 'active'.  I have a test user configured and am using that account.

I configured the app on the developer console about 24 hours ago, so surely any server delay as referred to in other queries should not be the problem by now.

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

Duh, sorry guys, the inventory, of course, shows purchased items so the correct answer was 0.

However, I also got an error using getSkuDetails() when using the account which had been nominated as the test account.  This was only resolved by adding the main Google account used on the developer console to the test device.

Comment: I am having the same problem. do you figure that out.